# Aligning labels at the center

Tags: html, css

I want to align 4 text labels at the center with a margin of 5px.

**The Code:**

```css
.header_section span {
  width: 100%;
}
.header_section min {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.header_section consume {
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_section">
  <span class="min">Min</span>
  <span class="consume">Consumption</span>
  <span class="avg">Average</span>
  <span class="max">Max</span>  
</div>
```

Do I need to add an id instead of a class?
Do I need to use the `label` tag instead of the `span` tag?

Comment: It might be easier to draw a picture of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: A class is used to define a generic css property set that it is intended to be used by many elements, so basically you have 4 items that are going to share the same properties set, you create 1 class, you assign it to them, and you define it once. please could you post the expected behaviour so people can be more precise in their help ?

Comment: Do you need to align them horizontally or vertically? `labels` are only necessary for form elements. You don't specifically need to set an `id` attribute unless you'll need to use it as a trigger for javascript event handlers, or something similar - or just need a higher specificity for declaring CSS rules in general.

Comment: you need to learn atleast the basics of css and html before jumping into it.

Comment: I know sorry for asking, this is actually a team work but all my team members left me high and dry. I already read a lot about the basics in html and css, but it's almost impossible to manage all of them within 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style>
 .header_section{
text-align:center;
 }
.header_section span {
   width: 100%;
  }
.header_section min {
padding-left: 30%;
padding-right: 5%;
}
.header_section consume {
padding-right: 5%;
}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below style can do this. It adds a left-margin of 5px to all spans except the first.

```
.header_section{
  text-align:center;
}
.header_section span + span {
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

A bit improved version is here in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/762zxbL7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to add an id instead of a class?

No

> Do I need to use the label tag instead of the span tag?

No. Labels are for texts associated to a input in a form. Maybe is a list, depending of the semactic meaning.

```css
.header_section{
  text-align:center;
}

.header_section li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header_section">
  <li>Min</li>
  <li>Consumption</li>
  <li>Average</li>
  <li>Max</li>  
</ul>
```